How to change the values ​of a model class?
I have a model class as follows:
package MyPackage.Models;

public class MyModel {
    private int id;

    public MyModel() {
    }

    public MyModel(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

From this class, I create two objects as follows and value them. I want that when I change the value of b, the value of a does not change. When I change the value of b, the value of a also changes.
MyModel a = new MyModel();
MyModel b = new MyModel();
a.setId(1);
Log.i("nadertag", "a=" + a.getId());
b = a;
Log.i("nadertag", "b=" + b.getId());
b.setId(2);
Log.i("nadertag", "a=" + a.getId() + "," + "b=" + b.getId());

It should be noted that this is a simple model class and the main program has many fields that I cannot place them one by one in the b variable.
Please show me the sample solution.

Just follow as below:
public class MyModel implements Cloneable{
    private int id;

    public MyModel() {
    }

    public MyModel(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

and wherever you want to get another object, simple perform cloning. e.g:
MyModel a = new MyModel();
MyModel b = (MyModel) a.clone(); 


This happens because when you write b = a, both variables point to the same object, originally assigned only to a. This happens because you passed only the reference to the object to b.
If you want to copy all attributes from the object in a to the object in band do not want to set them individually, you have to make a "deep copy" or "clone" the object. Take a look at this question for more info.
